# What does GLFW acronym stand for?

Tags: glfw

What does GLFW acronym stand for? http://www.glfw.org/ is the main website, but I cannot find any clue there. Evenhere on SO it has a tag but in the description the acronym is not explained.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at it and say Graphics Library Framework

Comment: Actually, the GL portion is for OpenGL.  The W is for Window.  I'm guessing the F is for Free, but I could be off on the F.  Regardless, the library is for facilitating the mixture of OpenGL with a Window context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, it used to stand for OpenGL FrameWork--[link](http://wiki.glfw.org/wiki/GLFW). I think I prefer some of the alternative interpretations given on the wiki, though.

Comment: That link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLFW) states "Graphics Library Framework". This makes sense, as GLFW is no longer an OpenGL focuses library, but also supports Vulkan.